# Android NDK - how to get coordinates from a tap and display them on a TextView?

Tags: java, c++, android-ndk, coordinates

I was wondering, does anyone know how I can get the coordinates from a tap (on the C/C++ side) and display them on a TextView (on the Java side)?  I am new to Android NDK development, so I need lots of help.

On the C/C++ side, I assume I have to use `AMotionEvent_getX` and `AMotionEvent_getY` to get the coordinates.  However, I would like to know how to pass these values over to Java and display them in a TextView.  Could anyone help me here?

Comment: This is a bit tricky to handle. You should have seen the native-activity example on NDK directory and in that one, input function is defined as part of the native activity using state->onInputEvent = engine_handle_input; line. This part is OK for your case but the problem is, text view should live inside a Java activity and you can't have two activities at the same time on Android. I don't know if you want to use intents to launch Java activities from C++, though it is doable. Other than that, calling Java functions from C++ is easy, just search for JNI examples and you will get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Android NDK is very limited. I handles touches in Java side and pass it NDK. I use NDK to render graphics  (OpenGL ES 2.0) and do game logic.

If you wish to pass touches to TextView then you do not need Android NDK.

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem. Apparently he is using text view to test if a callback mechanism from C++ to Java is feasible when touch events occur. And, NDK can be limited compared to Java side but definetely not "very" limited.

Comment: Look if he is a newbie and needs help then correct solution is to handle touches in Java side. First you get wider platform support. My father still have Android 2.2 phone. Second it is simpler to code and debug.

Comment: @Shuriken He does not ask which side is better at handling touch events and I can pretty well assume that he is aware of the fact that he can easily handle touch events in Java, but he does NOT want that. You can give it as an advice but it surely is not a solution to "handling touch events in NDK and sending them to Java text views". Moreover, what does this have to do with wider platform support? Can't NDK support any platform that supports Android and Java?

Comment: `android-9` (Android 2.3) has `input.h` that provides Touch API in NDK. Here is [Native Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html) that implements Touches in NDK. And shuriken was right I would not recommend doing that for newbie.

Answer (score 1):

To call java object from JNI/C++ you need to query the jmethod with env->GetMethodID and env->CallXXXMethod, google it and there are tons of example.

I would also suggest to get the input on java side, and propagate it to the C++ handlers, that is way you have more access to things like View and other objects.

Answer (score 1):

IF you use TextView to log touch values then I would recommend to use Android's logging. It is available in both NDK and Java sides.

**Java**

```
Log.i("GAME", "Touch X: " + x + " Y: " + y);
```

**NDK**

```
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"GAME", "Touch %f %f", x, y);
```